# checking a condition before activity is created in android

Tags: android, android-activity

I need to check a condition in the passed bundle value from the previous activity before the current activity is created.

I dont want to use the condition in `Oncreate()` method.

(I need to check the condition before the activity is created and decide whether to create activity or not)

How can I achieve this? Is there any methods which is useful for this?

Please Help.

Comment: Why don't you perform the check in the previous activity?

Comment: Because that acitvity is created after certain time using alarmmnager.
I need to check that time and the DB contents on  that time and  decide whether to create the actvity or not based on that time.Each day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

onCreate is the first method called in Activity creation so you'd need to check it there and if you don't want the Activity to run, call finish() from the onCreate method.

Can you check the condition before you start the Activity (via Intent I would guess)?

Comment: Thank you very much Chris,I tried that,If the condition is not satisfied i am finishing that acivity in oncreate method .But there is a blink/flicker in the screen, when the acitvity is finished.I dont want that flick to occur,How can i avoid that. Please Help

Comment: Can you give me some more details on how the activity is being created?

Comment: i have solved the problem,,,,,chris,thank you very much,I gave the condition in AlarmReciever Class which will recieve the broadcast reciever.......Then am creating the activity based on the condition